# React native complex view is really slow to re-render after upgrade from 0.66.5 to 0.71.3

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have my own calendar component that always renders three months at a time, each containing 6 weeks, each containing 7 days. Each day has a touchable-opacity, that sets the selected day of the calendar component. That adds up to a lot of views to re-render on every day change. The day components are memoized and shouldn't re-render unless the day was selected.

I used flipper to diagnose the render times. On react-native 0.66.5, the entire render took around 50ms on 0.73.1 it took over 500ms. I haven't changed anything else in the code.

The weird things is that the memoization seems to work only on the old version.

Comment: Do you have a minimal workable example that we can try on our end?

Comment: https://github.com/MichalBBBB/react-native-calendar  - This is a basic react-native project that utilises the same code that's in my app. It requires dayjs and flashlist dependencies and it takes nearly 400ms for every update.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a new date is selected or a new month is snapped in place, all the days in the three months (current, one prior, and one after) get re-rendered. Although you did do memo on `Day`, it does not have an impact because in `src/month.tsx`, each re-render calls `createMatrix` function which creates brand new components for every `Day` in the three months. Hence the performance hit.

One possible solution is to memoize your `Month`. Replace the line `export default memo(Month)` with the following

```js
export default memo(Month, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (prevProps.month !== nextProps.month) {
    // render new month due to month change
    return false;
  }
  if (
    typeof nextProps.month !== 'string' &&
    nextProps.selectedDay?.get('month') === nextProps.month.get('month')
  ) {
    // month does not change, but new date is selected. Only re-render the
    // month where the newly selected date is in it.
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

The comments shall be self-explanatory. The effect is that `Month` is only re-rendered under two conditions:

1. new month is in view
2. a new date is selected in the current month

With this memoization, as well as the memoization on `Day`, each time a new date is selected, only two `Day` components are re-rendered: one for the previously selected day and one for the newly selected day. I have not checked the new rendering time, but just visually, it is much faster.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, but it's still really weird that there is such a performance difference between the two react native versions.

Comment: I am actually more surprised that the old react native had good performance. I don't have the old version at hand, but it will be interesting to know whether in react native 0.66.5, all days are re-rendered after each new day selection.

Comment: https://github.com/MichalBBBB/react-native-calendar-old I created an app in 0.66.5 with the exact same code as the new version. The render time is at least 50x faster. I am really confused

Comment: I also tested it on android. The old version re-renders in about 10ms, the new one in about 30. It is not as bad as ios but still a problem.